# How to connect to MySQL server on localhost from inside of a Docker container in a windows machine?

Tags: mysql, windows, docker

I have seen the other ticket on Linux. My issue is on Windows.

I want my Java code running inside a Container to connect to MySQL on `localhost` OR i.e. `127.0.0.1`.

I am able to connect to MySQL with either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, from the host, but not from within the container.

I've also tried the network option which is `--net="host"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this hostname to connect from within a container to services running on the host: `docker.for.win.localhost`

- https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17060-ce-win18-2017-06-28-stable

Comment: Just to confirm this is still working with docker desktop 3.2.0 in spring 2021.  As far as my database is concerned, user 'myusername'@'localhost' gets a login when using the above host address so no need to create a different user or hostname.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1764#issuecomment-385910460
"Note that the official new name is host.docker.internal and docker.for.win.localhostis deprecated."
With that, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The net=host option does not work with Docker for Windows.

To connect to the host machine, you need to get the ip of the host machine on the docker network interface, and use that ip to connect.

Run the command `ipconfig` on you windows machine, and get the ip of the docker interface. Inside the container use that IP to connect to MYSQL running on the host machine.

Comment: Tried the above suggestion. No luck. Should I make changes on the MySQL side for above suggestion to work? Ipconfig showed the address 10.0.75.1 associated with DockerNat and my code running inside the container used this IP.

Comment: can you try to exec inside container and ping 10.0.75.1. `docker exec -it <container-name> bash`

Comment: Yes, I can successfully ping with this IP, but can't make MySQL listen on this IP. The above solution docker.for.win.localhost worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things in similar scenario:

- As noted [here](https://puvox.software/blog/useful-commands-for-docker-windows/), you might need to open local MySql console and to privilege (user should be created at first) the mysql user:

  ```
  CREATE USER 'myuser1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass123';
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.* TO 'myuser1'@'localhost';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```

  (instead of `localhost` you might also try your local network IP address, i.e. 192.168.1.123, or might be even a docker-IP address, like `172.1.x.x` )
- When connecting from application, in MySql host&port you might need to use `host.docker.internal:3306` (or whatever port). If that doesn't succeed, use local network IP address there too.

Answer (score -2):

docker.for.win.localhost does work if you are trying to connect mysql(service in windows localhost) from django docker container. keep 'HOST': 'docker.for.win.localhost', in setting.py